# AWS Redshift Snapshot Restore - Benchmark

Tags: amazon-redshift

Any benchmark available on restoring X TB snapshot from a N node Redshift cluster to another N node Redshift cluster?

For e.g. a 10 TB snapshot from a 12 node Redshift cluster takes 1 day to restore in another 12 node Redshift cluster? is it more like 1 day for the above or 1 week?

We are trying to get a benchmark.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> When you restore from a snapshot, Amazon Redshift creates a new cluster and **makes the new cluster available before all of the data is loaded**, so you can begin querying the new cluster immediately. The cluster streams data on demand from the snapshot in response to active queries, then loads the remaining data in the background.

["Amazon Redshift Snapshots"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/working-with-snapshots.html)

The new cluster (restore target) becomes available very quickly. You can start running all queries and Redshift will retrieve any missing data from the snapshot.

Total time taken to finish restoring all data from the snapshot depends on multiple factors:

- Is the cluster being heavily used during the restore? A cluster with no usage will complete the restore somewhat more quickly.
- What is the cluster size and node type? Larger nodes and larger clusters will have more network resources.
- Does the cluster use Enhanced VPC routing? This can improve network bandwidth further. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/enhanced-vpc-enabling-cluster.html

Comment: Thank you Joe. That helps. regards.